# How System.Web.httpUtility.UrlEncode works?

Tags: c#, .net

My C# project is in .Net framework 3.0 and i cannot use 3.5 (for some reason).
I've heard that .Net 3.5+ contains System.Web.httpUtility.UrlEncode/Decode methods, which i need.

I want to understand how they work, to code them myself or use some source code.
(It always was not clear for me, how this encodings/decodings are done)..

Comment: Do note that `System.Web.httpUtility.UrlEncode , System.Web.httpUtility.UrlEncode/Decode` methods exists in .Net 3.0 just reference System.Web

Comment: Yep, i cannot link this reference just for that 2 methods, actually System.Web is an Asp.Net server library ? Task is tooo simple for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [Uri.UnescapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.uri.unescapedatastring%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), available since .NET 2.0, and available in the Client Profile versions of certain .NET versions?

Comment: Thanks, but are they equal with system.web methods in results? Ill try, i just need this to work with some http api.